# Geometric probability exercise

Tags: probability, differential-geometry, curves

This is a problem in 49p. of the book differential geometry of
curves and surfaces - doCarmo

When a line $l$ in $\mathbb{E}^2$ meets a fixed circle $S$ of radius
$1$ in $\mathbb{E}^2$, then what is the probability $P$ that the
length of the chord is greater than $\sqrt{3}$

**Proof :** We assume that $S$ has the center $o=(0,0)$. Here we define
$x_l\in l$ where (the distance $|x_l-o|$ between $x_l$ and $o$) is (the
distance between $l$ and $o$).

Here when $l$ is divided into three pieces by the circle $S$, then
the line segment of a finite length is called a chord.

So $|x_l-o| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ iff the length of the chord has a
length $\geq \sqrt{3}$.

Hence the answer is the ratio between the probability that $ x_l$ is
in $\frac{1}{2}$-ball $B_\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability that $x_l$
is in $1$-ball $B_1$, $P=\frac{1}{4}$

But solution in the book is as follows (to me) : $$ P = \frac{ {\rm length}\ \partial
B_\frac{1}{2} }{{\rm length}\ \partial B_1} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Then which one is right ?

Comment: Look up the [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). It all depends on what measure you use on the space of lines (here, chords). Note that doCarmo has specified he's using the measure $dp\,d\theta$.

Comment: I feel that the formulation of the Q. is incomplete.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin : Thank you for your answer.